# Type Mismatch Javascript with Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an ASP Classic application I am trying to debug. There is a loop that iterates through a form's values and it is not returning the correct information. I added in an alert to show me the counter value but it is throwing an error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>   Type mismatch: '[string: "<script language="ja"]'
>   /WMD/SA/SA_exp.asp, line 14

Here is the code:

```
for x = 6 to Request.Form.count()-1
    response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert ('""" + x + """'); </script>")
```

If I put any other variable instead of "x" the alert works. How can I get the value of "x" into an alert?

Comment: The `Request.Form.Count` is a [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525985%28v%3dvs.90%29), not a Method. Refactor the line to be `For x = 6 To Request.Form.Count - 1`.

Comment: `alert ('""" + CStr( x) + """');`

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Write` is a sub, not a function. Don't surround the parameter with parens.

I've found that accidentally surrounding parameters with parens works sometimes, but only if the sub is expecting a single numeric parameter. In that case the parens are irrelevant to determining the value of the parameter so it coincidentally works.